# Does changing the position of an adjective, change the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: differences, adjectives, word-order

What are the differences in meaning between these sentences?

> 1. *The weather is hot on the island.*
> 2. *The weather on the island is hot.*
> 3. *On the island, the weather is hot.*

Do they mean the weather is usually hot on the island or the weather is hot on the island right now?

Comment: The title should say "position of adjective"

Comment: @JessWelch Adjective or subjective complement?

Comment: @JessWelch I think OP is moving the adverbial, "on the island".

Comment: @StoneyB I see what you mean, you're probably right

Comment: @StoneyB: You are right. Would it be different in meaning if I put 'on the island' at the different positions like the sentences above? Do they mean the weather is usually hot on the island or the weather is hot on the island right now? Thanks.

Comment: @Apirl No, there's no difference in meaning. Different positions create different focuses, which may be useful in different narratives.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thank you for your reply to my question. Could you please tell me what they mean? Do they mean the weather is usually hot or the weather is hot at the moment (a temporary situation) on the island? Thanks.

Comment: @Apirl Any of them might have either meaning, depending on the context and what else you have to say. The sequence of phrases does not change the meaning.

Comment: @StoneyB: According to you: "Different positions create different focuses,". What are the focuses on in the examples above? Could you please help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Apirl It will really depend on context. Just for instance, you might say "The mainland climate is temperate, but on the island the weather is hot", to throw the focus onto the final 'new-information' position.

Comment: @StoneyB:Thank you very much for your example. It's very useful. Could you please also tell me when I can put 'on the island' in the middle like example #2 and at the end like example #1? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Apirl The weather on the island is hot. Take shorts. ... The weather is hot on the island, and the best time for shopping is in the evening.

Comment: @StoneyB:Is it also OK to say:The weather is hot on the island. Take shorts. ... The weather on the island is hot, and the best time for shopping is in the evening. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Apirl Sure. It doesn't make a lot of difference - just rhythm, how you want to space the stresses, how it flows into what goes around it.

Answer (score 1):

All three of your examples mean the same thing. The most common usage would be (2):

> The weather on the island is hot.

You could also say:

> It is hot on the island.
>
> The island has hot weather.

If you want to note that the weather is hot at the moment:

> The weather on the island is unusually hot.
>
> The weather on the island is abnormally hot.

If you want to note that the weather usually hot:

> The weather on the island is traditionally hot.

Or, if you want to say both:

> The weather on the island is characteristically hot.

Comment: @Apirl: You're welcome! If you feel that this answered your question appropriately, please mark the little checkbox for others who have similar questions.